# Does Paypal use a specific tool to generate their REST API documentation

Tags: rest, documentation-generation

Paypal's REST API documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/) is really nice. Is this generated with a tool, or manually? If there is a tool used, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal is using [iodocs](https://github.com/paypal/iodocs) for API explorer. Here's the [tweet](https://twitter.com/ppalavilli/status/356846976689639424) from Paypal developer about the same. This is originally forked from an open source project [iodocs](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs) by [mashery](http://developer.mashery.com/).

Checkout more API explorers [here](http://whyidentity.blogspot.com/2012/07/dynamic-api-reference-generators-aka.html) similar to iodocs.